# Enol content tautomers

Tags: tautomer

> [image: Enol content tautomers]

I have figured out that 4 one will have the highest enol content of all, and the 1 structure would come after 4 in enol content, i.e 4 > 1. Then I got confused between the 2nd and the 3rd structures.

Please give a brief explanation for the answer as well.

Comment: What are the factors that determine enol formation? Is it easier to deprotonate an Ester or a ketone? Those are the sort of questions you need to consider

Answer (score 2):

> Enol content in 3 is greater then enol content of 2

Greater the acidic nature of alpha Hydrogen,greater is the tendency for Tautomeric behavior. H at alpha position in ketone is more acidic then H at alpha position in an ester.Pka values are shown below.The withdrawing power of ester is less compared to carbonyl group in ketone. Since lone pair on oxygen is in conjugation with C=O in ester,its withdrawing power decreases(as shown below).A more acidic α-hydrogen implies a weaker C−H bond. Summarizing,the enol content increases with the acidity of the enolic hydrogen.

$$\ce{carbonyl <=> enol}$$
$$\mathrm{K_{eq}=\frac{[enol]}{[carbonyl]}}$$

The equilibrium between keto and enol form is tipped to enol if H at alpha carbon is more acidic.

Hence enol content in 3 is greater then enol content of 2.

[[image]]

> Pka of cyclohexanone is as per this link: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB02060

Enol of 4th compound is aromatic and should be most stable.

Therefore extent of enol content must be 4>1>3>2.
As a general guide line the following can be used for predicting enol content.

[image]

---

The enol form of cyclohexanone  has bond angles around double bond other then 120${^o}$ as shown below using avagadro.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure cyclohexanone doesn’t have a pKa of 11.3! According to Bordwell (https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/) it’s 26.4, and acetone is 26.5...

Comment: @ PCK i will give source shortly

Comment: @ PCK , https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB02060 ,iwill try to include snapshot of the pka ,which you will find here.

Comment: Can you give a plausible explanation why (according to your numbers) cyclohexanone is a billion times more acidic than acetone? Is the solvent the same for your acetone and cyclohexanone values?

Comment: @PCK not according to my numbes,but from references as ptesented.

Comment: Shouldn’t we critically analyse data rather than just accepting it blindly? 11.3 is implausible

Comment: But maybe I’m being an idiot here - anyone else care to comment?

Comment: @ PCK https://owl.oit.umass.edu/departments/OrganicChemistry/appendix/pKaTable.html gives Pka of cyclohexanone as 16.7

Comment: So what’s the actual value? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ PCK https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Cyclohexanone#section=Computed-Properties pka 11.3